# Open file in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webmethod

I want to open file (image or pdf document). I use this function to do this:

```
[HttpGet]
public void Download(string filePath)
{
        try
        {
            var context = HttpContext;
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);
                context.Response.Clear();
                context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.Name + "\"");
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                context.Response.WriteFile(filePath);
                context.Response.Flush();
                context.Response.End();
            }
            else
                context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }
}
```

and it works fine. This function is called from javascript when user click right button. User sees window that allows to open or download file.
But now I want to display a message (instead of redirecting user to 404 page) when file wasn't found. I thought about changing function to WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
public void Download(string filePath)
{
        JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
        try
        {
            var context = HttpContext;
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                result.Data = new { Id = 0 };
                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);
                context.Response.Clear();
                context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.Name + "\"");
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                context.Response.WriteFile(filePath);
                context.Response.Flush();
                context.Response.End();
            }
            else
                result.Data = new { Id = -1 };
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }
        return result;
}
```

and call it from javascript using ajax. But in this case user can't see window which allows to open/download file.

What can I do about it?

Comment: When you say "display a message" do you mean that you want the new window to show a message instead of the 404, or that you don't want there to be a new window at all if there's a 404?

Comment: I want to stay at the page I'm in and show a jquery dialog or just write a message somewhere on the page where I can see a button to open/download file. The purpose of the function is to open a file when it exists or return a message to javascript function that I can display it when file doesn't exist.

Comment: Maybe use an ajax call to check if the file exists first.  If not, display your message.  If it exists, then you can call/redirect to your download action?